# SmartFormat - Override format method

Tags: .net-core, smartformat.net

I want to override Format method of SmartFormat.SmartFormatter class. Can anyone give me a sample or any idea on how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

The *SmartFormat* *SmartFormatter* class is not designed to be inherited.
The best alternative is to create an extension method. Example:

```cs
public static class MySmartExtensions
{
    public static string CreateComment(this SmartFormatter sf, string comment, string submittedBy)
    {
        return sf.Format("Comment from {0}: {1}", submittedBy, comment);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```cs
Smart.Default.CreateComment("The comment", "joe@example.com");
```